# Linear fishnet grid over layer with latlong coordinates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, vector-grid

In QGIS I have a city boundary layer which I want to transform into a simple fishnet grid with 30m spacing. The boundary layer is in geographic degrees and the only solution I found so far is choosing a projected coordinate system which produces a rotated and uneven grid. What could I do to overcome this?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Gis.StackExchange, when you say choosing a projected coordinate system does that mean you used a projection on the fly or saving your vector layer in another projection ?

Answer (score 1):

Move to a square planet? You can't overcome the fact that the Earth is an oblate spheroid. If you want a regular grid in meters, it will not appear regular in degrees. If you create a regular grid in degrees, it will not have fixed spacing in the X axis. You can fudge things so rectangles in degrees have approximately the same area, but then the spherical rectangles will be taller closer to the poles. It might not be obvious over smaller areas, but they still will not have fixed lengths.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to project your boundary data into your local projection before making your [fishnet grid](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_creation_tools/creategrid.html). If you then need to [rotate](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#rotate-feature-s) your fishnet grid to a certain orientation, you can do that using the editing tools.

Comment: Depending on the local projection, even this might not be possible, because the rotation might not be constant.